# Meaning of operator in certain formula

Tags: algorithms

I'm attempting to learn more about stock calculations as I progress through software engineering, there has been a few mathematical problems I've faced but usually found pretty good explanations of the actual formula and could create a coherent program around, this time I don't know where else to go, here is a screen grab of exactly the formula i'm stumped on and if someone could explain the purpose of the plus and minus sign that would greatly be appreciated, thank you and have a great rest of your day! (Ps. This is part of the Binomial Option pricing model if this information helps in anyway)
[Formula Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAegY.png)

Comment: You should type it...

Comment: @ClumsyAllen It would help to add `$$u=\frac{s{}+}s; d=\frac{s{}-}s$$` to your question, which is the MathJax way to type what your screengrab shows: $$u=\frac{s{}+}s; d=\frac{s{}-}s$$  Also, as notations differ a lot between finance, computer science, and various branches of mathematics, it would help a lot to know what book/article/course/etc this is from.  I mean, doesn't your source document not have some kind of explanation or legend?